# Which email addresses should I activate for a website?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

While checking the log files for a website (let's say `http://example.com`) I manage, I saw that there is lot of spam being addressed to email addresses like `genericusername@example.com` or `othergenericusername@example.com`, which do not exist nor have ever existed, and are not listed anywhere on the website. `Postfix`blocks these emails with `Recipient address rejected`.

At the same time there are mails being send to `info@example.com`or `administrator@example.com`, … e.g. mail addresses that would make sense somehow. Some of which might exist for the website while other might not, and even those that exist, might not be listed anywhere on the website.

Is there a list of default email addresses, like `info, contact, admin, administrator, webmaster`, that one should enable for each website?

I know I could enable a catch-all address, e.g. `info@example.com` to which all emails which are send to non-existing addresses are redirected. But I fear that this would result in spam in the inbox.

Basically: Which common addresses should I enable, which could be used for legitimate correspondence, while not gathering too much spam mails?

A client recently applied for an SSL-Certificate and in the application-form from the certificate provider it was stated, that during the process, they will try to contact the technical contact of the domain as well as send an email to some 'standard' addresses: (`admin@www.example.com, administrator@www.example.com, webmaster@www.example.com, hostmaster@www.example.com, postmaster@www.example.com, admin@example.com, administrator@example.com, webmaster@example.com, hostmaster@example.com, postmaster@example.com`)

Comment: See also: [Is there any list of email addresses reserved because of security concerns for any Public Email Service like Gmail / Yahoo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104811/is-there-any-list-of-email-addresses-reserved-because-of-security-concerns-for-a)

Comment: Note 3 of your answer on that question answers the second part of my question quite well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a privacy/information security researcher, I disagree with the accepted answer's statement "No ... institution will try to legitimate communicate you to an email address that they will guess...". When we run scans and observe vulnerabilities or privacy violations present on a page, we want our research to result in a remediation, so we want to report our findings to webadmins. Depending on concrete researchers, we will try common email aliases (`admin@`, `webmaster@`, `security@`) and maybe automatically extracted contact from footer. For the protection of your users, we would be happy if you read them.

Of course these emails are sent by a bot, one cannot expect to manually navigate thousands of websites to collect emails. But to decide if an email is unsolicited, you should use a good spam filter.

Let me support this by several resources:

1. [RFC 2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt) specifies common aliases `POSTMASTER@`, `WEBMASTER@`, `ABUSE@`, and `TROUBLE@`. The RFC's purpose is to define exactly emails that you should monitor.
2. [1](https://academic.oup.com/cybersecurity/article-abstract/2/1/83/2629556), [2](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2663716.2663755), [3](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/stock), and [4](https://publications.cispa.saarland/1190/) all study how reachable are webadmins by these aliases.
3. [Have I been pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/DomainSearch) requires you to check email address at `security@`, `hostmaster@`, `postmaster@`, or `webmaster@`. if you want to check emailserver domain for leaks. There are other authorization methods, but this is the most convenient.

Finally, my personal choice would be `webmaster@` (I prefer it over `admin@` because of the RFC 2142) and `security@` or `privacy@` since these seem more specific and I would use them to address my issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a common or default email address that you should create for your website.

Speaking of experience, I suggest to make any e-mail account you want and publish it to your e-mail account, preferably as an image in order not to being fetched by spam bots.

No service provider or company or institution will try to legitimate communicate you to an email address that they will guess that it might be your "common" email address or the general common email address for website owners (like webmaster@ or info@).

Whoever wants to legitimate contact you, he will first visit your website to find your contact details or even better contact you through your contact form. In other case, if someone tries to guess your email by typing the "common" ones, he will be probably a spammer (human or bot).

**Concerning your question update**

During the SSL Certification purchase process you will be asked to which of the above email address you mentioned, you want to receive verification email, and future ones concerning your SSL Certification status. You have also to declare the same email address during the CSR encrypted text generation on your server.

They will not just randomly send you an email to one of the "standard" email addresses you mentioned.

So make sure that you have created this email address before you declare it to the registration process. I mostly use `ssl@mydomain.example` which in most cases is given as an option too during the SSL Certificate registration.

Comment: I agree with you, but do you also have an explanation for my update to the question?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly,

Comment: From the wording on the form (offline pdf to be send via snail mail/fax) I'm pretty sure they would bulk email all the given addresses and there was no place to define a preferred address for technical contact, only one for the person requesting the certificate. (I made sure one of the addresses is active.)