# Is there a standardised/recommended email address for legal/copyright contact/disputes?

Tags: email, standards

[RFC2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt) defines many standard email mailbox names for technical/administrative web service contacts.

My question is whether something similar exists for legal/copyright contact details, and if not - is there something that is generally accepted/understood by people who would want to use these contact addresses?

For example, people involved with information security commonly know that the default security contact address for a web service is `security@example.com`.

Is there an equivalent for legal/copyright/DMCA contact info?

For example:

- legal@example.com
- copyright@example.com
- dmca@example.com
- takedown@example.com

Comment: See also: [Is there any list of email addresses reserved because of security concerns for any Public Email Service like Gmail / Yahoo?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104811/is-there-any-list-of-email-addresses-reserved-because-of-security-concerns-for-a)

Comment: I do not think there is a standard but you could start by trying to use the email.addresses published in whois records of the concerned domain name. Specifically the registrant and admin ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That is a good idea, although I am actually asking about this for the contact page of my own website, rather than trying to raise a dispute myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've received DMCA takedown requests my web servers have forwarded me the DMCA requests from legal@example.com and support@example.com. I imagine that there is no standardized email address for these requests, though those 2 addresses seem fairly standard to me.

If you use legal@example.com it implies that you have a legal team and/or are legally savvy. And this could potentially deter people from sending you frivolous DMCA requests when it's unnecessary and not within their lawful right to do so.

I would personally use legal@example.com, support@example.com or DMCA@example.com. Just make sure that you check that inbox regularly because you have 48 hours to remove the page due to the DMCA request.

It's also pretty important that this address be added to your whois record. Or that you also check your email address in the whois record database for DMCA requests. Because DMCA requests can be sent to the whois email address and so you do not want to miss those requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your point about trying to deter potentially false DMCA requests. I definitely don't host any strictly copyrighted material, at the most it is a CC license, but I just like to be as compliant as I can where possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the contact information of the whois record is used. Technically, these are to be real addresses and monitored. Otherwise the domain can be shutdown. All systems that use online or other mechanised reporting use these  contact emails. I have worked with a few systems and they used the whois contact information. Outside of this, sometimes a human will use contact information from a website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess when WHOIS privacy is enabled, the "abuse" contact normally sends the message to the registrar/hosting provider to deal with.

Comment: @JamieOnUbuntu With the privacy set up for my domains, all contacts are the same email and they all get to me via the email address shown by the privacy company. I get more than one copy of the email to each of the email addresses I provided when setting up the domain name. It is a shotgun approach which is good. However, specifically which one are used may not be clear for all systems. Technically speaking, the site owners email should be the primary contact over others such as technical contact. Cheers!!